# Get ADODB to parse unicode in where clause, prefix with N

Tags: sql, vb.net, adodb

I'm updating one of our older applications to support unicode. It's littered with literal sql queries (`SELECT * FROM ...`) against the **ADODB libraries**. Most of this is working OK until I get to the SEEK code. We have some methods that transform user data into a where clause. So it parses a dictionary and produces a string. If the user is looking for something with unicode data I need to append the statement with an N. However, when I add this to the text and pass the command through the recordset.open, **ADODB** throws an exception :

> Failed to Parse SQL

Existing SQL output:

```
SELECT * FROM ACCOUNT WHERE NAME ='ӐӕӔҔҖӸӽӳ'
```

this goes through the record set, but fails to retrieve any data.

What I need, but is throwing the exception:

```
SELECT * FROM ACCOUNT WHERE NAME = N'ӐӕӔҔҖӸӽӳ'
```

Is there some special magic I need to do to the record set to allow the N through? Or is there another approach I need to take for this to work? (and yes, I realize we SHOULD be parameterizing the queries and that's the long-term fix, but this is spaghetti code).

Comment: Is that the *exact* error message you get, are you sure it's coming from ADODB, and are you sure that it happens with the exact modified command text you've included in the question? I ask because I've never seen that error message before, despite having written valid SQL that ADODB does not understand, yet happily passes on to SQL Server. (You are using ADODB with SQL Server, right? The `N''` syntax is specific to SQL Server, so otherwise, that would be a reason why it doesn't work.)

Comment: I just double checked. The exact exception is "Failed to parse SQL." The command looks identical to what I posted above. I'm trying to connect to a SQL Server 2012 Express.

Comment: Okay, the problem appears to be with the specific provider i'm using. It's something with the SalesLogix OLEDB dll. Nothing to do with ADODB.